# Using Purrr Functions to iterate manual work

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have a set of code that I am using to scrape data by year.  Each year has a large amount of data (545 MB-ish in the global environment as a `tbl_df`).

I have been successful in getting the code to run manually by season, but I'm trying to upgrade the code to iterate over multiple years.

My code initial takes dates stored in a `tbl_df` and eventually passes them as arguments to a function in another package.

Single Year Programming

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(baseballr)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'quantmod':
#>   method            from
#>   as.zoo.data.frame zoo

df <- 
tibble::tribble(
   ~year,   ~startDate,     ~endDate,
  "2021", "2021-04-01", "2021-10-03",
  "2020", "2020-07-23", "2020-09-27"
  )


# Single Year
df <- df %>% 
  filter(year == "2020")

# get regular season start and end dates for scrape
start_date <- df$startDate %>% lubridate::ymd()
end_date <- df$endDate %>% lubridate::ymd()

# create sequence of dates for scrape function
weekly_dates <- seq(start_date, end_date, by = "1 week") %>% as_tibble()

weekly_dates <- weekly_dates %>%
  rename(start_date = value) %>%
  mutate(end_date = start_date + 6) %>%
  mutate_all(as.character)

# Example of df  
weekly_dates
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    start_date end_date  
#>    <chr>      <chr>     
#>  1 2020-07-23 2020-07-29
#>  2 2020-07-30 2020-08-05
#>  3 2020-08-06 2020-08-12
#>  4 2020-08-13 2020-08-19
#>  5 2020-08-20 2020-08-26
#>  6 2020-08-27 2020-09-02
#>  7 2020-09-03 2020-09-09
#>  8 2020-09-10 2020-09-16
#>  9 2020-09-17 2020-09-23
#> 10 2020-09-24 2020-09-30

safe_statcast <- possibly(scrape_statcast_savant, otherwise = NA)

# Pass along referenced columns as the two arguments in the referenced function
return <- map2_dfr(weekly_dates$start_date, weekly_dates$end_date, ~ safe_statcast(.x,
                                                                                   .y,
                                                                                   player_type = "pitcher"
))
```

I'm looking for help with 3 things:

1. Run some form of the code above but allowing multiple years of data with each year grouped together
2. How would I save each years `df` as it's own `*.Rds` file?  Something that uses the year column from above as it's own file name.  I.E. `saveRDS(return, here::here("data-raw", paste0(year, "_data.rds")))`
3. How would I mutate the same column across each year?